# Using express app.locals in html

Tags: node.js, express

I have an local variable in web.js:

```
var app = express();
app.locals.userName;
```

when I render this page:

```
app.get('/finish', function(req, res){
  res.render('finish');
});
```

I need to use an instance of userName in finish.handlebars:

```
<div class="page-header">
<h3>FINISHED</h3>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    rootRef = new Firebase('MyFireBases');
    currentMessageRef = rootRef.child('BusinessName');
    currentMessageRef.set(userName);
</script>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to know what userName is in finish.handlebars...

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
res.render('finish', {userName: 'admin'});
```

If you need access to all app.locals without binding like above then you must align res.locals and app.locals together.

```
res.locals = app.locals;
```

I think that middleware is a best place for it.

Comment: how to use these res.locals in html?

Comment: You can't use it in html because it is a severs-side variable. What kind of a problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: index.pug file is able to access the isAuthenticated variable but doesnt work when i use index.html or call a javascript method. I am new to this web coding and trying to understand how these variables are being used.

Comment: The http-server (Node.js/Express) renders `index.pug` into `index.html` and send it as answer to an user browser. In the browser there is no way to get any server-side variables.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebar variables are expanded using `{{ VAR }}`, which I don't see being used in your template.

Use this instead:

```
currentMessageRef.set('{{ userName }}');
```

(this assumes that `userName` does not contain single quote characters).